# Json Transformation/Validation in Scala

Tags: json, validation, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use json transformation from play 2.3 to transform and validate a jsvalue, the value is optional but if it is present it should pass the isUrl call, but the code doesn't compile ...

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.GenericValidator
import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._



def transform(js:JsValue):JsResult[JsValue]={
    val transformer: Reads[JsObject] =
        (( __ \ 'website).json.pick(Reads.optionWithNull[Option[JsString]] keepAnd filter(
          ValidationError("Website URL is not valid"))((in:String) => GenericValidator.isUrl(in))))

    transformer.reads(js).map{e=> e }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add necessary `import` statements for this code snippet. It makes it easier to focus only on the problem.

Comment: Sure thing, imports are added.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is using [`Reads`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads$) which also acts as a validator, according to [Play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonCombinators#reads).

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object Test extends App {

  // defining a Reads which acts as a validator as well
  def url(implicit reads: Reads[String]): Reads[String] = 
    Reads.pattern( """\blahblah""".r, "error.url")


  val OptionalUrlFormat: Reads[Option[String]] =
    (__ \ 'website).readNullable[String](url)


  private val jsonString = "{\n  \"website\": \"http://example.com\"\n}"
  private val json = Json.parse(jsonString)
  val maybeUr = Json.fromJson(json)(OptionalUrlFormat)
  println(maybeUr.get)

}
```

Comment: Sure, I am trying to use the coast-to-coast design explained here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonTransformers

Comment: So using the new stuff from `Play 2.3` is not an option?